# C++ STL vs. Boost.Intrusive allocation performance

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers

I often heard that the boost library containers are more performant than the STL ones, because they don't allocate the objects internally. But isn't it as fast or even faster if we use a memory pool for the allocator template parameter of STL's templated containers? This one could cache memory chuncks of same size. So, we can reuse these chuncks which should be really fast.

I'm looking for a high performance random access and sequential container. In addition, I need thread safe versions of them.

EDIT:
I want to create a list which stores elements in last-recently used order.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Technically speaking, the heap is a memory pool, or at least one sort of memory pool. To have a better-performing allocator than the heap allocator, you probably need a memory pool specially crafted for your data, or for your scenario.

Comment: (As far as [performant](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/05/10/performant-isn-t-a-word.aspx), a ["word"](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/05/10/performant-isn-t-a-word.aspx) I often fall into the habit of using...)

Comment: What is "last recently-used order"? What determines a "use" Does the data have a timestamp?

Comment: A "use" is determined by accessing an element.